# LINQ for querying a DTO for a specific Name-Value pair in a generic and recursive manner

Tags: c#, linq, collections, linq-to-objects, dto

I have a DTO which is composed of a series of collections. Each of these collections again hold various name-value pairs in their InnerLists.

Is there a way to query the DTO for a specific name and get its value...irrespective of the Collection or the position in the InnerList it is in?

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrates the structure of the members in the DTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this. Notice how I have two different collections in my class but I am exposing a unified iterator, which is used in **Main** function to treat it like one collection and print out all the even elements in all collections.

```
 class Foo : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        List<int> first = new List<int>();
        List<int> second = new List<int>();


        public Foo()
        {
            first.Add( 1 );
            first.Add( 2 );

            second.Add( 11 );
            second.Add( 12 );
        }


        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var f in first)
            {
                yield return f;
            }

            foreach (var f in second)
            {
                yield return f;
            } 
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo();

        foreach (var d in f.Where(x => x % 2 == 0))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your doubt, but if what you want is make a query on all those collections in one single Linq expression, you could use Concat().

```
var list1 = new List<String>();
var list2 = new List<String>();
var list3 = new List<String>();

// get an IEnumerable that contains all lists
var concatEnum = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3);

// do everything you want...
var myLinqResult = concatEnum.Select(item => item.ToLower()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DTO
{
  public List<Dictionary<string, object>> collectionList { get; set; } //just a simple example

  public object Get(string key)
  {
    if(collectionList != null)
    {
       foreach(var c in collectionList) //iterate through each collection
       {
        /*If your collection list is a of type List<ICollection>, you have to find the type of c 
        using reflection and then use a switch-case to fetch the key appropriately
        depending on it's implementation. 
        For simplicity I'm assuming all the collection objects are dictionaries*/
         if(c.ContainsKey(key)) 
            return c[key];
       }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```